# How to get the country adjectival?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert a country code to its adjectival equivalent. I am currently using RegionInfo which will get me the country name.

```
RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(languages[0]);
subtitle = ri.NativeName;
```

If the country code is 'en', this will give me England but what i want is 'English'.

So, how can I can get the country adjectival?

Thanks

Comment: Just put 'ish' on the end of everything. ;)

Comment: @EdPitt But it will be `Englandish` ? `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül Englandish, Americaish, Turkeyish. People understandish.

Comment: Are you sure that every country has a single *form* that will apply (even assuming that only a single language is spoken in that country)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no class in the standard .NET API that contains information about citizen-naming adjectives.

You can, however, use the `CultureInfo` class to convert from a country code to a list of spoken languages - taking an arbitrary element from that list often gives the right answer (but **not** always, as in "Chinese (Simplified)")

For instance:

```
var cultureInfos = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("CH"));
var cultureInfo = cultureInfos.SingleOrDefault();
string language = cultureInfo.EnglishName;
```

But I'm afraid the only option that will work **correctly** for all cultures is to create your own mapping.

```
Dictionary<string, string> adjectiveMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
adjectiveMap.Add("en", "English");
adjectiveMap.Add("cn", "Chinese");
// etc. etc...
```

If you're prepared to take on this task, check out this wiki page! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_for_countries_and_nations

Comment: `EnglishName` is a property rather than a method: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.englishname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh yeah. Whoops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `RegionInfo`, better try to use `CultureInfo`.
There you can try it like the following:

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo(languages[0]);
subtitle = c.DisplayName;
```